# Export data from SSMS from all tables like '%vt_%'

Tags: sql-server-2012

I have to transfer data from ~500 tables to a database on another server.  The pattern of the table names is basically '%vt_us%'.

I've run into the Kerberos double-hop issue with my initial attempts at using DML to run through all the tables like '%vt_us%', and am not authorized to change the security settings in order to transfer this data.

Is there a way to get the SSMS to transfer data from all tables like '%vt_us%' to another database, without needing to manually check each table in the export menu?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to accomplish this task by:

1. Creating a new database on the same server and transferring all the tables with names like '%vt_us%' into that database
2. Backing up this new database
3. Copying the backup file over to the other server
4. Restoring the database on the server.
5. Inserting the data by DML into the appropriate tables in the destination database.